# Pass table name to select statement from cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I use values returned from Cursor as table names in mysql procedures ?

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
select table_name, column_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema = 'foo' and table_name like 'bar%';
OPEN cur;

loop1: LOOP

FETCH cur
INTO table_val, column_val;

IF no_more_rows THEN
  CLOSE cur;
  LEAVE loop1;
END IF;
update table_val SET column_val ...
```

This throws error that `foo.table_val doesnt exist`. How can I get the actual table name to be passed to the select statement ?

Comment: To use a dynamic name for a table you have to use prepare statement (dynamic sql). DO you know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `update table_val SET column_val ...` into

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', table_val, ' SET ', column_val, ' = whatever WHERE...');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

But note that you can not parameterize table and column names. This only works with values.

Comment: It throws error for @sql, my msql version is 5.0.21, checked with SET `@sql = CONCAT()` as well

Comment: @2-Stroker Updated answer. Please try again. And **always include error messages.**

Comment: I believe it should be `EXECUTE stmt` instead of `@sql` :)

Answer (score 0):

I will also share my fix. hope it will help someone too.

```
-- set to "$$" as we have ";" inside of Procedure. MySQL will be confused.(is this part of Procedure or should I run it now?)
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTable()
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _table_name CHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
            WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_type = "BASE TABLE";
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;
    My_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO _table_name;
        SET @my_table_name = _table_name;

        IF done THEN
          LEAVE My_loop;
        END IF;

        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

        SET @stmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', @my_table_name, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;'); 
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stmt; 
        EXECUTE stmt1; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;   
        
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
            
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;

END$$

-- set to normal. ";" 
DELIMITER ;
```